# boost::thread execution

Tags: multithreading, boost, mutex, halt

I have a class `ChunkManager` that has a few (supposed to be) asynchronous methods. These methods handle tasks in my game engine such as loading the map blocks (similar to Minecraft) on a different thread so as not to completely halt the main thread (they are lengthy operations)
Here is one of those methods:

```
void ChunkManager::asyncRenderChunks(){

    boost::thread loadingThread(&ChunkManager::renderChunks,this);
}
```

Where renderChunks looks like:

```
void ChunkManager::renderChunks(){
activeChunksMutex->lock();
      for(int z=0; z < CHUNK_MAX; z=z+1)
      {
        for(int y=0; y < CHUNK_MAX; y=y+1)
        {
            for(int x=0; x < CHUNK_MAX; x=x+1)
            {

            activeChunks[x][y][z]->Render(scnMgr);

            }
        }
    }
    activeChunksMutex->unlock();
}
```

This should work, right? However it crashes when this runs. I have a feeling it has to do with what I do with the thread after it's created, because if I put

> loadingThread.join();

in the aforementioned method, it works fine, but the main thread is halted because obviously its just waiting for the new thread to finish, effectively bringing me back to square one.
Any advice?
Sorry if this is a retarded question, I am new to the concept of threads.
Thanks.

Update (4/9/2013):
I found this gem: http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/
..and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can join the thread, it must be joinable.

As it says [in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.destructor2):

> When the `boost::thread` object that represents a thread of execution is destroyed the program terminates if the thread is **joinable**.

You created a local `thread` object and *immediately* let it go out of scope: it is destroyed when `ChunkManager::asyncRenderChunks` returns.

Either:

- make it a detached (non-joinable) thread

  ```
  void ChunkManager::asyncRenderChunks() {
      boost::thread loadingThread(&ChunkManager::renderChunks,this);
      loadingThread.detach();
  }
  ```
- or create the `thread` object elsewhere and keep it alive

  ```
  class ChunkManager {
      boost::thread renderingThread;
      bool renderChunkWork;       // work to do flag
      Chunk activeChunks[CHUNK_MAX][CHUNK_MAX][CHUNK_MAX];
      boost::mutex activeChunksMutex;
      boost::condition_variable activeChunksCV;

      bool shutdown;              // shutdown flag

      void renderChunks() {
          for(int z=0; z < CHUNK_MAX; ++z)
              for(int y=0; y < CHUNK_MAX; ++y)
                  for(int x=0; x < CHUNK_MAX; ++x)
                      activeChunks[x][y][z]->Render(scnMgr);
      }

      void renderChunkThread() {
          boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> guard(activeChunksMutex);
          while (true) {
              while (!(renderChunkWork || shutdown))
                  activeChunksCV.wait(guard);

              if (shutdown)
                  break;
              renderChunks();
              doRenderChunks = false;
          }
      }

  public:
      ChunkManager()
          : loadingThread(&ChunkManager::renderChunkThread, this),
          renderChunkWork(false), shutdown(false)
      {}

      ~ChunkManager() {
          { // tell the rendering thread to quit
              boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> guard(activeChunksMutex);
              renderChunkShutdown = true;
              activeChunksCV.notify_one();
          }
          renderingThread.join()
      }

      void asyncRenderChunks() {
          boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> guard(activeChunksMutex);
          if (!renderChunkWork) {
              renderChunkWork = true;
              activeChunksCV.notify_one();
          }
      }
  };
  ```

NB. In general, creating threads on-the-fly is less good than creating your threads up-front, and just waking them when there's something to do. It avoids figuring out how to handle a second call to `asyncRenderChunks` before the last one is complete (start a second thread? block?), and moves the latency associated with thread creation.

---

### Note on object lifetime

It's important to realise that in this code:

```
void ChunkManager::asyncRenderChunks() {
    SomeType myObject;
}
```

the instance `myObject` will be created *and then immediately destroyed*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Also, how would I go about starting new tasks once I have the permanent thread implemented? Edit: Also, does the thread destroy itself once the function returns AFTER it returns if I detach it?

Comment: Nope, if you detach the thread it's no longer joinable, so this is ok.

Comment: if the thread of execution is detached, the `thread` object will still be destroyed, but it won't wait or stop the thread or terminate the program.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would vote you up but I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes, because in the current version of `Boost.Thread`, you have to either join() a thread or `detach()` it - otherwise `~thread` [would terminate the program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.destructor2). (In earlier versions `~thread` used to call `detach()` automatically.)

So if you don't want to join the thread - just detach it:

```
boost::thread loadingThread(&ChunkManager::renderChunks,this);
loadingThread.detach();
```